# Failed to push local files to Cpanel existing repository

Tags: git, version-control, cpanel

I'm working with a project which already hosted in a Cpanel. But when i try to push my local files to that location i got an error. I read most of QA in here but nothing work for me. That is the reason i post this as a new question.

```
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (Working directory has unstaged changes) error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://somestring@mydomain.co.nz:21098/home/somestring/fna.mydomain.co.nz'
```

I followed this [Cpanel written guide line](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/guide-to-git-how-to-set-up-deployment/) to accomplish this task. But i got this error.

Very first time i clone this project from the Github private repository to Cpanel then I cloned my project from the Cpanel to my pc, and i try to changes things in my local project, then t try to push that changes back to Cpanel.

[image]

[image]

In Git log i can saw this error

```
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (Working directory has unstaged changes) error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://somestring@mydomain.co.nz:21098/home/somestring/fna.mydomain.co.nz'
```

I tried these commands

1. git push
2. git push -u origin HEAD

Result is same.

Comment: The error message fro Visual Studio Code says that you should 'Pull' first. Try running this command: `git pull`

Comment: After running git pull console shows "Already up to date." then when i try to push using git push command it shows that above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

The remote branch you are trying to push to has changes you need to merge into your local branch before you can push. To do so, as suggested in the MessageBox, run `git pull` to merge the remote changes into your local branch.

Comment: After running git pull console shows "Already up to date." then when i try to push using git push command it shows that above mentioned error.